# How to fill in the value of the ListItem. Chevron Component attribute？

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-elements

```
<ListItem.Chevron Component={() => {
  return (
    <Iconfont
      name={"ic_in_24"}
      size={24}
      color={"#48D597"}
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate(item.route)}
    />
  );
}} />
```

Although there is an error, it can be used

`Error Message`

TS2769: No overload matches this call.

Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ListItemChevronProps, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null', gave the following error.

Type '() => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'typeof Component'.

Type '() => Element' provides no match for the signature 'new <P = {}, S = {}, SS = any>(props: P | Readonly

): Component<P, S, SS>'.

Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ListItemChevronProps): ReactElement<any, any> | null', gave the following error.

Type '() => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'typeof Component'.

Icon.d.ts(16, 5): The expected type comes from property 'Component' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ListItemChevronProps'

Icon.d.ts(16, 5): The expected type comes from property 'Component' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ListItemChevronProps'

`This is the type of the props`

```
typeof React.Component
```